# Capturar evento volver atrás de android desde el navegador

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, eventos

Buenas, no se si el título está muy bien pero no sabía como explicarlo bien ahí.

Bueno explico mejor cual es mi pregunta, estoy haciendo una web me gustaría poder capturar con js o jquery  el evento que produce el botón de navegación de volver atrás, a estos me refiero:

[image: El de la flechita de volver atrás]

He estado buscando ya por ahí y he probado varias cosas y nada... no me capturan el evento, a ver si vosotros me podéis echar una ayudita ^^

Un saludo

Comment: agrega lo que hayas hecho para mejorar la pregunta.

Comment: pero la app es nativa o es con js? Si es navita sólo hay que hacer un `override` de `onBackButton` en la Activity

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacerlo con Jquery, si lo tienes disponible:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        window.history.pushState('forward', null, './#forward');
        $(window).on('popstate', function() {
          alert('Back');
        });
});
```

Haces push de un nuevo elemento en el historial, si este se retira al pulsar el boton back, el evento popstate va a saltar.